# Selenium script captures first few items out of 100

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I've rceated a script to scrape different collection names from a webpage traversing multiple pages. The script can parse first 13 names from each page out of 100 names. One such collection name looks like `Pudgy Penguins`. How can I capture 100 names instead of only 13 from different pages of that site using selenium?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

link = "https://opensea.io/rankings"

def scroll_to_the_bottom():
    check_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight;")
    while True:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        try:
            WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(lambda driver: driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight;")  > check_height)
            check_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight;") 
        except TimeoutException:
             break


def get_collection_names(link):
    driver.get(link)

    while True:
        scroll_to_the_bottom()
        for item in WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"[role='listitem'] [class$='Ranking--row']"))):
            collection_name = WebDriverWait(item,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"[class$='Ranking--collection-name']"))).text
            yield collection_name

        try:
            button = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//button[contains(@class,'Buttonreact__StyledButton')][./i[contains(.,'arrow_forward')]]")))
            driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();',button)
            WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.staleness_of(item))
        except Exception as e:
            return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    for collection_name in get_collection_names(link):
        print(collection_name)
```

`Scrolling to the bottom of every page seems not to have any effect on the number of results the script produces.`

Comment: If you check the page you're looking at and open your browser inspect panel. You can see that the page doesn't list all the items. It only list the one displaying at screen (for you, 13), so it's not too demanding for your computer. 
You can see when you scroll that the values within the list get updated. So, I think you should try to see how to scroll for the height of a screen in Selenium. Never tried that myself, hope you'll find the solution!

Comment: Check out the edit @Jules Civel.

Comment: worth noting that "visibility_of_all_elements_located" returns if at least 1 item is found.  Which means it doesn't necessarily wait for an entire list to load.   Your for loop is not necessarily getting the full results after the scroll.  If the list updates after the scroll, you need to wait before getting your element array to iterate through.  Either use a sleep or catch Stale Element exceptions on the item's method and re-call.  (Functionize the find_elements and recall if caught.)

Comment: FYI the site https://opensea.io is protected with `CloudFlare`, which I triggered when developing a solution for your question.  So I would suggest adding some delays into your scraping code.

Comment: So, it is working well?

Comment: I have no opinion. If it is working well, I am also okay. Hope to be helpful for you.

Comment: And if it is helpful for you, please vote me and tick my answer. Thanks and best regards.

Answer (score 1):

I have checked your description and source code and I think there are many elements. So it doesn't load at one time. For solving this, scroll down to the bottom step by step. So, I have changed function `scroll_to_the_bottom` as below :

```
def scroll_to_the_bottom() :
    H = driver.execute_script('return document.body.scrollHeight;')
    h = 0
    while True :
        h += 300
        if h >= H :
            break
        
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo({}, {});".format(0, h))
        time.sleep(1)
```

So, embed above code into your code, we can change it as below :

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


link = "https://opensea.io/rankings"


def get_collection_names(link):
    driver.get(link)
    unique_items = set()
    while True:
        item = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"[class$='Ranking--collection-name']")))
        H = driver.execute_script('return document.body.scrollHeight;')
        h = 0
        while True :
            h += 300
            if h >= H :
                break

            for element in WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"[class$='Ranking--collection-name']"))):
                if element.text not in unique_items:
                    yield element.text
                unique_items.add(element.text)
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {});".format(h))
            time.sleep(1)

        try:
            button = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//button[contains(@class,'Buttonreact__StyledButton')][./i[contains(.,'arrow_forward')]]")))
            driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();',button)
            WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.staleness_of(item))
        except Exception as e:
            return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    for item in get_collection_names(link):
        print(item)
    driver.quit()
```

Hope to be helpful for you. Thanks.

Comment: I have no opinion. If it is working well, I am also okay. Hope to be helpful for you.